# Passing variables from predecessor task to Current task

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

Is there a way to set variables in Task 1 and pass them to the child task? It looks like every task has a different session so value of variable doesn't transfer in a task tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [SYSTEM$SET_RETURN_VALUE](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/system_set_return_value.html):

> Explicitly sets the return value for a task.
>
> In a tree of tasks, a task can call this function to set a return
>   value. Another task that identifies this task as the predecessor task
>   (using the AFTER keyword in the task definition) can retrieve the
>   return value set by the predecessor task.

There is an example in the link.